# Reference join on a combined key in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, join, azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to filter data based on a reference table on a combined key. I acutally found a solution that seems to work:

```
    SELECT 
        i.id
        , i.timestamp
        , i.PropertyName
        , i.PropertyValue
    FROM iothub AS i
    LEFT JOIN Reference AS R
    ON CONCAT(i.id, '|', 'i.PropertyName) = R.uid
    WHERE R.keepIt = 1
```

But if I do this I get a warning that my query contains a JOIN with no key selector which will be translated into a CROSS JOIN.

[image: Warning emitted by Azure]

I tested the method and it seems to result in the correct results, but I'm afraid that there may be side effects later on through a maybe CROSS JOIN. Or may I just ignore this Azure warning, as it does not apply in my case?

Answer (score 0):

The `CONCAT(i.id, '|', 'i.PropertyName) = R.uid` is not a key selector, since left side of the equality is an expression and not a column reference.
So this will be translated to the CROSS JOIN followed by a filter as the warning suggests.

This is a warning and does not affect the functional correctness of the result.

You can project the expression as a column before doing reference data join and then it will be proper key lookup join. Here is what your example query will look like:

```
    SELECT 
        i.id
        , i.timestamp
        , i.PropertyName
        , i.PropertyValue
    FROM (SELECT id, timestamp, PropertyName, PropertyValue,
                 uid = CONCAT(id, '|', PropertyName)
          FROM iothub) AS i
      LEFT JOIN Reference AS R
        ON i.uid = R.uid
    WHERE R.keepIt = 1
```

Of cause, the sub-select can also be put into a separate step.

Comment: Are you sure the SELECT FROM (SELECT) syntax works in Azure Stream Analytics? because it doesn't seem to work on my environment